# How to use SAML to connect Zoho Desk with Google Identity Platform?

Tags: zoho, google-identity

I have Google Identity Platform setup for my app.

My app is also using Zoho Desk.

I want to use the Zoho Desk ASAP widget to display the help widget on my site. To automatically login my users (stored on the Google Identity Platform) into the Zoho Desk widget I need to setup SAML SSO User Authentication inside Zoho Desk.

These are the settings Zoho Desk asks for when setting up SAML SSO:

1. Remote Login URL
2. Remote Logout URL
3. Public Key (Provide Public Key in .txt or .pem extension file)
4. Algorithm (RSA or DSA)
5. Entity ID (Issuer)

But I have no idea where to find these details within the Google Identity Platform.

Inside Google Identity Platform I tried clicking "New identity provider" and choosing "SAML", but I can't find any of those details. In fact it seems they're asking for similar things.

Comment: Hi, Is the issue resolved?

Comment: @ZeenathSN After more reading I figured out this was not possible. Google Identity Platform only gives federated SAML. It does not act as a SAML provider.

Comment: Okay, you can post it as an answer, so that it helps the community.

Comment: I have no answer. I think it can't be done. If you can figure it out please post the answer.